# jQuery mobile reference error "a is undefined"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm referencing the following jquery files in my header:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='$root/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css'>

<script type='text/javascript' src='$root/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js'>
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
```

I get the following error:

```
a is undefined
```

The error references the entire jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js file.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The order of the script are wrong.**  Also close the `link` tag.

**jQuery mobile is called after jQuery.**

Here is the `CDN-hosted files`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

From your point of view:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='$root/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='$root/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js'>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This removes the error. But half my website now doesn't load. Any ideas how this could have caused it?

Comment: @user2699231 Glad I was able to help you.  I can't guess with this information.  Check console for any errors.

Comment: There are no errors on the console. I don't even know why switching those statements around would disturb any of the other functionality of the website (none of it is uses jquery).

Answer (score 3):

You have to include `JQuery` first and then `JQuery Mobile`. This is because `JQuery Mobile` is using `JQuery` and when you include `JQuery Mobile` first it will look for `JQuery` funcitons, which won't be included at this stage.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```